# How to assign a score to each sublist?

Tags: python, dictionary, sublist

I have a dictionary and a list with sublists of separate words:

```
lst=[["love", "apple", "@"],["user", "hit", "hate"]]

dict{"love":3, "hate":-3}
```

I need to iterate through the sublists and evaluate if there is the word from the dictionary in the sublists and to assign a value to each sublist. The desired outcome is:
3
-3

I have tried the code below but it gives me the score of each word in the sublist. Where is my mistake?

```
def evaluation(list, dict):
    score=0
    for i in dict.keys():
        for sublst in list:
            if i in sublst:
                score+=dict.get(i)
            print(score)
```

Comment: What do you mean by assigning a value to a list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use variable names as `list` or `dict`, you are shadowing builtins. And you don't reset `score` value in each iteration to `0`.

You can do this:

```
lst=[["love", "apple", "@"],["user", "hit", "hate"]]
d = {"love":3, "hate":-3}

score = [sum(d.get(val.lower(), 0) for val in sublst) for sublst in lst]

print(score)
```

To print:

```
[3, -3]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And how can I get it checked in lower  case? In the dictionary I have all the words in lower case but in the list there is upper and lower case.

Comment: @codeforfun You use then `d.get(val.lower(), 0)`. I updated my answer.